Characterization of Algebraic Number Fields of a Certain Degree
Let $\mathcal{I}_d(\mathbb{Q})$ be the set of irreducible rational polynomials with degree $d$.
Consider the equivalence relation $\sim_d$ on $\mathbb{Q}[x]_d$, defined by, $$p\sim_d q\iff \mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle \approx \mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle q(x)\rangle.$$
For $d=2$, thanks to the quadratic formula, its easy to see that, $$p\sim_d q \iff \sqrt{\frac{\Delta(p)}{\Delta(q)}}\in\mathbb{Q},$$ where $\Delta(ax^2+bx+c)=b^2-4ac$ is the quadratic discriminant.
For higher degrees $d$, what is the characterization of $\sim_d$? Are there general results? What about specifically $d=3,4,5$? It is worth noting that thanks to the primitive element theorem, this would actually be a characterization of all algebraic number fields of degree $d$.
